# iOS App behaves differently when the app detects beacon in the background/Closed

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon, ios7.1

I have developed a App with beacon detection functionality. With the new updates from the Apple to detect the beacon while the iOS device is Locked. My app actually detects the beacon even while the app is closed and when the iOS device is locked.

But the Problem here is:

While the App is closed, and the user(with iOS device) is near to the Proximity region, this makes the App to wake up and it calls this function:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Instead of calling the beacon proximity function:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

I'm unable to alert the user when this happens on detection of beacon proximity.

How can we resolve this issue. I'm unable to understand why it executes the "DID FINISH LAUNCHING WITH OPTIONS".

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in the background http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

Comment: @BarefootCoder Yes I have the logs that shows me the lines that got executed and the time and the App was closed completely.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to post your code that sets up CoreLocation to answer exactly what is going on.  Two tips:

1. It is normal for `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to get called if an app is completely closed when iOS launches it as a result of iBeacon detection.
2. Ranging generally will not work in the background, so I can understand why `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region` might not get called.

You can only expect the **monitoring** callback to get called in the background.  It is possible to get ranging callbacks for a few seconds, but only if ranging is set up in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or in the monitoring callback.

Comment: Ranging will work in the background for the Proximity response, and we get the response from the above didRangeBeacons function. <br/>   And what it means by ranging is setup in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Does it mean initiating the beacon region.